# run python script from batchfile doesn't work by using java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, python, batch-file, processbuilder

I need to run a batch file from Java code, in which a python script shall be executed and it's not working.

Run the batch file by doubleclick, the python script executes correctly. Run the batch file with JAVA ProcessBuilder doesn't work completely. textoutput from batch file(-->echo) is printed, but python isn't called. How can I fix that? I've even tried to run the Python Script directly with ProcessBuilder, but no output is generated either.

**run Python directly in JAVA**

```
String pyPath = "D:/<...>/my_py_file.py";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","D:/Python27/ArcGISx6410.5/python",pyPath);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

This isn't working as well as:

**run Batch file in JAVA, calling my_py_file.py**

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","D:/<...>/my_bat_file.bat");
Process proc = pb.start();
```

This is my bat-file:

```
@echo execute script
@echo off
cd\
d:
cd Python27/ArcGISx6410.5
@echo Python Version
python -V
@echo start script
python D:/<..>/my_py_file.py
exit
```

**OUTPUT by doubleclick:**

```
execute script
Python Version
Python 2.7.13
start script
**pythonOutput**
```

**OUTPUT by using ProcessBuilder:**

```
execute script
Python Version
start script
*nothing*
```

Comment: Why is this tagged groovy?

Comment: Because the code is embedded in groovy file running in tomcat.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and (continue to) use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's missing in your "run Python directly in JAVA" implementation is that you don't process the output after `Process proc = pb.start();`

For example, you can take redirect the output-stream to a file like this:

```
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(FILENAME));
```

(The file referenced should already be created before redirecting there)

Or you can channel it into an InputStream that you feed into an InputStreamReader for further processing, like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
```

So either way, add it after `Process proc = pb.start();`

Comment: No...Sorry...i only missed to add this line i  my question. Of course i commited processbuilder to Start

Comment: Ok sorry, re-read your question. I do think you are missing the ouput from Python, because it's a sub-process. How are you collecting your output?

Comment: It's "simple" print command (execution Time of script). It's like the Java-Code (in fact its a groovy script running under Tomcat -but code's the same) is unable to access Python?!

Comment: Yeah so in that case your Python process is a sub-process, which is why its output is not coming through. You could try adding `pb.inheritIO();` before the start command. So, like this: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(YOUR ARGS);  pb.inheritIO(); Process proc = pb.start();`